# TortoiseSVN: when I try to commit, it doesn't show new files

Tags: svn, addition, commit

Using Tortoise SVN Client Version 1.9.2, Build 26806 - 64 Bit on Windows 7 64 bit Professional K

In a folder - I can find new file

[image: Folder showing new file]

Commit page - can't find new file

[image: Commit page not showing new file]

Please help me.

Comment: Have you **added** the new file to SVN? In Windows Explorer - go to the file, right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Add`

Comment: show `svn st --no-ignore` for this dir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have *some* ignore-pattern defined in directory, any unversioned file, which match any pattern, will not be shown in TSVN dialogue (as expected)

[image]

while

```
WC>dir /B
1.txt
1.dat
1.tmp
```

because

```
WC>svn pl -v .
Properties on '.':
  svn:ignore
    *.bak
    *.tmp
```

and it's (ignoring) also visible with full status

```
WC>svn st --no-ignore
 M      .
?       1.dat
I       1.tmp
?       1.txt
```

Comment: Remember to also check the ignore pattern under "TortoiseSVN > Settings > General > Global ignore pattern", which applies to all repositories on the system.

Answer (score 3):

In additional to already mentioned in the accepted response: in TortoiseSVN  windows client you can see/modify ignored patterns in folder properties dialog (right mouse click to folder name ->properties->Subversion)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In commit window on the bottom you have checkbox - "Show unversioned files". Make sure it's checked.